# Apache and virtual host issues

Tags: apache, virtualhost

Feel like I am going slightly mad/round in a circle here so hoping someone can give me some pointers.

I have a Debian instance on AWS running apache. Inside of my /var/www/ folder I have another folder called dineosaw.com. I have a conf file called dineosaw.com.conf which looks like the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerAdmin xxxx@gmail.com
  ServerName www.dineosaw.com
  ServerAlias dineosaw.com

  DocumentRoot /var/www/dineosaw.com/public
  <Directory /var/www/dineosaw.com/public>
    Options -Indexes
    AllowOverride All
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from All
  </Directory>

  ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
  CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

I then have forwarded my domain name (www.dineosaw.com) to the server by using the following address: http://52.56.144.228/. This however only took me to the apache default page. So I tried: http://52.56.144.228/dineosaw.com/ but this results in a 404 error.

Can anyone give me any pointers as to what I might be doing wrong/need to look in to? I would be very grateful.

Comment: Name resolution looks fine, but it is not possible to connect to that http server.

Comment: The most likely answer here is that you indeed forwarded to that ip based address. That is not how the web works. This (probably) results in a request to the ip address with a HOST header _not_ holding the intended domain name. You do _not_ want to forward to that IP address, but to the host name.

Comment: 1) Don't do [this](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains/how-do-i-forward-my-domain-name-to-another-website-5044/), do [this](https://www.123-reg.co.uk/support/answers/Domains-Archive/Domain-Configuration/how-do-i-point-my-domain-name-to-an-ip-address-1200/) 2) there are some more `.conf` files, share them also

Comment: From the little reading I have done, the hostname is changed in the /etc/hosts file. But do I want to change my hostname when I might want to run multiple websites? I thought the point of virtual hosts was to allow me to run multiple websites off of the same server?

Comment: @Dusan Bajic, what other conf files do you think it would be helpful to see?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to address this name-based virtual host by IP address, you'd need "ServerAlias 52.56.144.228"